# Duplicate ID error for fragments in SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

I have read a number of posts regarding destroying the fragment or page to avoid duplicate ID but the problem here is that a fragment is displayed in the view page and when i press the same button again I get the error Duplicate ID.

Below is the code for fragment and controller :

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout">
 <Page id="masterAp" showHeader="false" enableScrolling="true" >    
     <TileContainer
      id="getTiles"
      tiles="{myModel1>/0/TileCollection}">   
      <StandardTile    
      title="{myModel1>title}" 
    icon="{myModel1>icon}"  
        number="{myModel1>number}"
        numberUnit="{myModel1>numberUnit}"  
        info="{myModel1>info}"
        infoState="{myModel1>infoState}"  
              press="handleTilePress"/>       
       </TileContainer>  
       </Page> 
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

The code for controller : Please advice what line of code is missing to avoid duplicate ID error : Uncaught Error: Error: adding element with duplicate id 'getTiles'

```
onPressGoToMaster1 : function() {
    var oDialogFragment = sap.ui.xmlfragment("yca_web111_dashboard.fragments.panel2",this.getView().getController());
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("data/dataAP.json");
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "myModel1");
    var oPage = this.getView().byId("detail");
    oPage.insertContent(oDialogFragment);
    this.getSplitAppObj().to(this.createId("detail"));

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to add the fragment every time you move to page with id: detail. Simplest solution would be to check if you have already added the fragment.

- If yes (fragment is present), don't add the fragment again to page with id: detail, and navigate.
- If no (fragment is not present), fetch the fragment, add to page and the navigate.

Code:

```
onPressGoToMaster1 : function() {
    if (!this.oDialogFragment) {
        this.oDialogFragment = sap.ui.xmlfragment("yca_web111_dashboard.fragments.panel2",this.getView().getController());
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("data/dataAP.json");
        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "myModel1");
        var oPage = this.getView().byId("detail");
        oPage.insertContent(this.oDialogFragment);
    }

    this.getSplitAppObj().to(this.createId("detail"));

};
```